# qt creator после переименования проект не компилируется

Tags: компиляция, qtcreator

Qt creator соединен с QNX на виртуальной машине.

После того, как я переименовал файл `название.pro` в `название_2.pro` (внутренности так же потерпели подобное изменение) компиляция стала давать ошибку:

```
Cannot run: No command given.sh: slog2info: cannot execute - No such file or directory
```

Целевая папка, куда должен пойти скомпилированный исполняемый файл, существует.

Название.pro:

```
TARGET = НАЗВАНИЕ

TEMPLATE = app

qnx
{
  target.path=/home/НАЗВАНИЕ
  INSTALLS += target
}
```

Подскажите, как уйти от ошибки? Или как правильно переименовывать проекты и компилируемый файл?

Comment: Добавьте больше инфы структуру каталога проекта, и полный скрипт qmake. У поясните откуда взялся given.sh

Answer (score 0):

sh: slog2info: cannot execute - No such file or directory

Данная ошибка не имеет фактический никакого значения для компиляции.

Cannot run: No command given.

Эта ошибка возникла в связи с тем, что параметры проекта не переняли адрес, куда положить и откуда запустить исполняемый файл.

После того, как заново поменял файл проект.pro и настроил параметры, компиляция прошла успешно.

P.S. given.sh - компилятор просто при выводе ошибки почему-то не перенес строку(как я понял). после '.' должен быть перенос строки.

Comment: так проект компилировался, но не запускался?